# Узнать какие правила валидации применены к полю

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :gender, :state, :photo, presence: true
end
```

Подскажите, как мне проверить в шаблоне есть ли свойство presence у поля (например :name)?

Comment: Правильно понимаю вопрос - есть ли какой-то автоматический способ узнать наличие валидаций у каждого поля, когда вы пишете форму во вьюхе, чтобы не ходить в модель их проверять, и на этом основании сгенерить валидации на фронте?

Answer (score 0):

У моделей есть метод [validators_on](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validators_on), он выдаёт список валидаторов для заданных полей. Так что можно вот так:

```
Animal.validators_on(:name).any? do |validator| 
  validator.kind_of?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator)
end
```